# Android calculating time difference from time set in TimePicker

Tags: android, time, dialog, datetimepicker

I am trying to calculate the time difference between two time variables. The 1st variable is set like this:

```
Time StartTime = new Time();
StartTime.setToNow();
```

The second variable is set with a time picker where the user can set the hour and minutes:

My time picked dialog code:

```
//Time Picker Dialog
    Date d2 = null;
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{       
    switch(id)
    {
    case dialog_id: 
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, hour, minute, true);
    }       
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int hour_minute) 
    {           
        hour = hourOfDay;
        minute = hour_minute;           
        textBox.setText(hour + " : " + minute);
        updateTime(hour, minute);       
    }
};
//fixing the "0" removal
private void updateTime(int hours, int mins) 
{
    String minutes = "";
    if (mins < 10)
        minutes = "0" + mins;
    else
        minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

    String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':').append(minutes).append(':').append("00")
            .append(" ").toString();
        textBox.setText(aTime);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault());
        try
        {
            d2 = format.parse(aTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        final long difference = d2.getTime() - StartTime.toMillis(true);

        diffMinutes = difference / 1000;

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Arrival time changed to: " + aTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and I want to know what is the difference between the Start time and D2(aTime) but I am getting a negative answer - 1649478203... something like that. I debugged it and saw that the data value in "d2" is set in year 1970. How can I fix this problem and calculate the difference correctly in seconds?

Comment: My guess is that you're getting that date because the default date is january 1st, 1970, so you're creating a date object with that date and your set time.

Comment: yep how can I set the date to be the today's date

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the GregorianCalendar class instead of the Date format. Use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) constructor, taking today's date for the year, month and day. You can set the seconds to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer I had to update my update time method.  Here is what I changed:

```
  //fixing the "0" removal
private void updateTime(int hours, int mins) 
{
    String minutes = "";
    if (mins < 10)
        minutes = "0" + mins;
    else
        minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

    String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':').append(minutes)
            .append(" ").toString();
        textBox.setText(aTime);
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentTime);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, pickedHour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, pickedMinute);


        final long difference = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - StartTime.toMillis(true);

        diffMinutes = difference / 1000;

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Arrival time changed to: " + aTime, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```